# Office 2007 Web components and Microsoft Office spreadsheet 12.0 usage in Visual Studio C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, office-interop, office-2007

I'm unable to find Microsoft Office spreadsheet 12.0 COM component/control in Visual studio COM components tab of ToolBox.

And also i couldn't able to use/find 'OWC12.dll' in order to add the same in Toolbox control items.

Since I'm able to see something called 'owc11.dll' of 'Microsoft Office spreadsheet 11.0' in Toolbox COM components items tab.

But i need the latest COM component related to spreadsheet of Office2007 in my Visual Studio 2008 WinApp project.

In case if not available of 12.0 component then please tell me how to add an excel 2007 spreadsheet as a control in Visual Studio2008/2010 Windows Application project.

Please provide me detailed explanation and process of adding the same with code .

-B.S

Answer (score 0):

You can add a excel work book to your windows form by using the AxSpreadsheet control. To use this control you need to add a reference of AxInterop.OWC11.dll and Interop.Office.DLL.

http://dotnetcodelearner.wordpress.com/2012/12/19/displaying-the-excel-workbook-in-windows-form-using-axspreadsheet/